# Using mod rewrite with wildcards for dynamic creation of URLs

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the following:

```
RewriteRule ^tribute-acts/([^/.]*)/?$ /entertainment/act-view.html?act_name=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

which changes:

```
http://mysite.com/entertainment/act-view.html?act_name=elvis
```

to:

```
http://mysite.com/tribute-acts/elvis
```

Works great, but what if the `tribute-acts` part was dynamically generated and different for each link? Therefore endless possibilities...

Can I use a wildcard instead of `tribute-acts/` ?

I tried the following, using `(.*)`, but it didn't work:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/([^/.]*)/?$ /entertainment/act-view.html?act_name=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this rule:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^[^/]+/([^/]*)/?$ /entertainment/act-view.html?act_name=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Thanks, but doesn't work, if I try e.g. mysite.com/hello/elvis it still sees hello as the act_name variable and not elvis

Comment: Oh sorry my mistake, see edited answer now. I didn't need to group first part of path.